# owner change in case with child record relationship master detail

Tags: security, relationships, childrelationship

I am changing the owner of the case and I have a master-detail with viewed notification object.everything is working fine .the problem is in changing the owner of the case does not transfer the viewed notification records related to that 
case instead it deletes.

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Is `viewed notification object` a custom Object?

Comment: yes it's a custom object

Comment: Is it possible that its being deleted in trigger of master object?

Comment: There is no delete trigger event on master

Comment: Is change owner custom ? or standard SF functionality?

As the behaviour you mentioned is of cascade delete, if you delete parent it deletes all the childs in master detail.https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=relationships_considerations.htm&type=5

Comment: I am changing the case owner manually.it should transfer the viewed notification object records to the new owner. but it's not doing that it's deleting the child records